# css is not working for inside of inside folder jsp in web content

Tags: css, jsp

I have two folder's in my web content admin & super admin.In that i have some admin related & super admin related jsps respectively. I have one css folder which contains stylesheet.css file.

This is the structure of my project

[image]

In my jsp page i added this line inside the header tag

```
<link href="css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

When my jsps are inside the webcontent folder this css is working fine.
but when i moved my jsp pages into separate folder css is not working.
I dont  now why it is happening.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

When your files are in the WebContent folder, the file path for the CSS IS correct (which is why it is working). When you move them to another folder, you need to modify that path, because you are using relative path for your CSS file.

So, for example, if you placed your JSP page inside a folder called "MyPages", which is also inside "WebContent", the link to the CSS file would need to be:

```
<link href="../css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The JSP page is looking for the CSS file relative to itself. Since you don't have a CSS folder inside of "MyPages", you need to traverse up a level (which is what the ".." is doing), and then look inside the "CSS" folder, and then you will find your "stylesheet.css" file.

".." simple says to "look up one directory to find this file". However, you could also have:

```
<link href="../../css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

This says to look up 2 directories.

```
<link href="../../../css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

This says to look up 3 directories.

And so on.

Comment: Yes @JesseEarley it is working. can you please explain those two dots(.). why we need to use.

Comment: ".." simply says to "look up one directory". "../.." says to "look up 2 directories", and so on. When using relative paths, you need to specify the difference in directory depth from the current file, and the file you want to look to.

I also updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify correct relative path to your CSS file. When your JSP file placed inside a folder the path should be like this,

../css/stylesheet.css

Or else you can specify a absolute path, like,

http://mydomainname.com/css/stylesheet.css

read about relative path, [here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm)